# Insert data in H2 using HTML form

Tags: forms, scala, h2, playframework-2.4, playframework-evolutions

I'm using Play! Framework 2.4. I can make a table and insert data via the evolution .sql scripts but how do I setup my `Appication.scala`, `routes` etc to make a form insert data?

PS I'm quite new to Play

Comment: Did you check out the tutorial? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaHome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way play fromework recommends is using helper and template system.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaForms

But if you want to try with plain html and handler request in the controller by your own so you can try this:

`Application.scala`

```
def save = Action { implicit request =>
//here handle params from html form, 
//this will return Option[Map[String,ArrayBuffer]]                                                                     
val optionMap = request.body.asFormUrlEncoded
println(optionMap)
//saving things here
Ok("saved")
```

}

in `plain html form`

```
<form action="/savedata" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="text" name="lastName" />
<input type="submit" />         
</form>
```

`conf/routes`

```
POST   /savedata                        controllers.Application.save
```

hope this helps.
regards

Comment: the form goes in savedata?

Comment: @creativename no, the html form goes in `index.scala.html` at app/view folder.  `GET /` triggers `controllers.Application.index` who will render `index.scala.html` (and the html form you added) and when you do submit in the html form this will call `POST /savedata` who will trigger  `controllers,Application.save` method

Comment: it worked, thanks. but where did you find/get all this information? i cant seem to find any good documentation about Play, H2 and forms, did you learn it yourself?

Comment: @creativename your welcome and just you need to understand how HTTP communication protocols work and you could understand how handle http request with any MVC Web frameworks. Play framework has good documentation.. maybe you are searching with wrong keywords combination. e.g. You don't need to look at google "how save in H2 from HTML form in play" H2 or mysql or postgres are indiferent.. you just need to know how persist with the default play ORM. regards ;)

Comment: how to i tell the save method to "link" the database column to the table input name? e.g. column test1 should connect with 

'<input name="test1">'.

Comment: @creativename That is not too directly as you  can think.. as I told you there are many ways to do that but all of those are not too directly as you can think... look at this:  [lifecycle](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/resources/manual/working/scalaGuide/main/forms/images/lifecycle.png)